# React, how to get data after clicking on checkbox?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, express

I have two React components: ul list and each li item, which is a flash-card. In each item there are two strings: searching word and its translation (api.source, api.target) and also checkbox. After clicking on the checkbox and later on the button (CardList.js) I would like to get my data and send it to my backend. Can anybody please tell me how to get these two strings and pass them into  addFlashCards function? Right now I have hardcoded it as dataSet

```
const CardsList = ({ fetchedApi }) => {
  const addFlashCards = () => {
    const dataSet = [
      {
        apiSource: "sampleDataCheckbox",
        apiTarget: "sampleDataCheckbox2",
      },
      {
        apiSource: "sampleDataCheckbox",
        apiTarget: "sampleDataCheckbox",
      },
    ];

    const url = "/api/saveToDB";
    axios
      .post(url, { data: dataSet, user: "SOME USER" })
      .then((res) => {
        const fetchedData = res.data;
        console.log(fetchedData);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  };

  return (
    <div className="cards-list">
      <button onClick={addFlashCards}>Add</button>
      <ul className="cards-list__list">
        {fetchedApi.map((api) => {
          return <CardItem api={api} />;
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CardsList;
```

```
const CardItem = ({ api }) => {
  const [isChosenCard, setIsChosenCard] = useState(false);

  const clickedCheckbox = () => {
    setIsChosenCard(!isChosenCard);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <li className="card-item">
        <input
          className="fiszkiBox"
          type="checkbox"
          onClick={clickedCheckbox}
        />

        <div className="flip-card">
          <div className="flip-card-inner">
            <div className="flip-card-front">
              <p id="api-source">{api.source}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="flip-card-back">
              <p className="api-target">{api.target}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </>
  );
};

export default CardItem;
```

Many thanks!

Comment: If possible create a jsfiddle working link of this scenario with some hardcoded data and share that link here

Answer (score 0):

So as summary you have a list which you render and you want to select items which would be sent to backend. In this case you can add a empty array to your CardList by using useState hook which will contain the selected items.

```
const CardsList = ({ fetchedApi }) => {
  const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState([]);
  const addFlashCards = () => {
    // Here you can do some kind of check with mapping the selectedItems Array, as you need

    const url = "/api/saveToDB";
    axios
      .post(url, { data: selectedItems, user: "SOME USER" })
      .then((res) => {
        const fetchedData = res.data;
        console.log(fetchedData);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  };

  function selectItem(item){
    // So below, we do it to make component render by creating new array instead of mutating the current array. Actually try to play with code, you can even remove these and mutate current and set.
    let selectedItemsArray = [...selectedItems];

    // Here below, we check if selectedItem already exists in selectedItemsArray, if it exists we would like to remove it right? if it does not exist, we just add it to array by pushing it.
    let itemCheck = selectedItemsArray.find((arrayItem) => arrayItem.source === item.source);

    if (itemCheck) {
        // Here if selected item was in array, we just remove it by filtering the array
        selectedItemsArray = selectedItemsArray.filter((arrayItem) => arrayItem.source !== item.source)
    }
    else{
        // Here selected item was not in our array so we just push it
        selectedItemsArray.push(item)
    }
    setSelectedItems(selectedItemsArray);
  }

  return (
    <div className="cards-list">
      <button onClick={addFlashCards}>Add</button>
      <ul className="cards-list__list">
        {fetchedApi.map((api, index) => {
          return <CardItem api={api} onItemSelected={item=> selectItem(item)} />;
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

const CardItem = ({ api, onItemSelected }) => {   
  return (
    <>
      <li className="card-item">
        <input
          className="fiszkiBox"
          type="checkbox"
          onClick={() => onItemSelected({
              source: api.source,
              target: api.target
          })}
        />

        <div className="flip-card">
          <div className="flip-card-inner">
            <div className="flip-card-front">
              <p id="api-source">{api.source}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="flip-card-back">
              <p className="api-target">{api.target}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </>
  );
};
```

These codes should work, hope you got the logic also. This approach would be logical in your case.

Comment: thank you for your help. I didn't explain exactly what I wanted to do. After choosing  checbox from the item user have to click on the button to prove that choice.  <button onClick={addFlashCards}>Add</button>. Instead of hardcoded dataSet I want to have a value t(api.source, api.target) from the item,that user chose by clicking on checkbox (each item has checkbox, api.source, api.target)

Comment: ok let me edit it as you would like it, its almost same actually.

Comment: Ok made the edit, just check it now it should be as you need. Dont forgot the check the codes by logging, if there is some mistake or etc.

Comment: Can you please write some comments to the selectItem function? I don't understand exactly what is there. Many thanks :)

Comment: Ok added some comments, my suggestion is just add console.log to every step and check the data. Then you will be able to understand the flow better.